# Is it possible to delete the records having same foreign key in different table with single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete the records in all the multiple table having same foreign key ID with single sql query. I given the example below,

```
Table Name : basetable
id | column1
---|---------
 1 |  BCol1
 2 |  BCol2

Table Name : Reftable1

id | BaseTableID | Column1
---|-------------|--------
 1 |      1      | RT1Col1
 2 |      1      | RT1Col2

Table Name : Reftable2

id | BaseTableID | Column1
---|-------------|--------
 1 |      2      | RT2Col1
 2 |      1      | RT2Col2

Table Name : Reftable3

id | BaseTableID | Column1
---|-------------|--------
 1 |      1      | RT3Col1
 2 |      2      | RT3Col2
```

In above three reference table I want to delete records having BaseTableID=1 with single mysql query. Is there is any possibilities please share your idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
DELETE r1, r2, r3
FROM Reftable1 r1
JOIN Reftable2 r2
JOIN Reftable3 r3
WHERE r1.BaseTableID = 1
AND r2.BaseTableID = 1
AND r3.BaseTableID = 1
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/200d1/2)

If some tables may not have matching rows, this LEFT JOIN should do it:

```
DELETE r1, r2, r3
FROM basetable b
LEFT JOIN Reftable1 r1 ON b.id = r1.BaseTableID
LEFT JOIN Reftable2 r2 ON b.id = r2.BaseTableID
LEFT JOIN Reftable3 r3 ON b.id = r3.BaseTableID
WHERE b.id = 1
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/329b9/1)

Comment: +1 I think (haven't tested) that this would not delete any rows if at least one of the tables didn't have a row to be deleted. To handle the case where there isn't a related row in some of the tables, I think these will really need to be outer joins. (I could be wrong.)

Comment: @spencer7593 I think you're right. But if it could be any table missing the rows, it has to be a FULL OUTER JOIN, and MySQL doesn't support that.

Comment: or, query the base table, with left joins to each reftable. If we aren't guaranteed a row in the base table, then we create an inline view (derived table)  `... FROM (SELECT 1 AS id) bastetable LEFT JOIN ... ON basetable.id = `

Comment: @spencer7593 I think we are guaranteed a row in the base table, since it's a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to specify `on cascade delete` when you create the table.

```
baseTable id references BaseTable(id) on delete cascade
```

For more info please refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: OP didn't say he wanted to delete rows from `basetable`; he asked to delete only rows from the `ReftableN` tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete across a join like this:

```
DELETE FROM basetable
INNER JOIN Reftable1
  ON basetable.id = Reftable1.BaseTableID
INNER JOIN Reftable2
  ON basetable.id = Reftable2.BaseTableID
INNER JOIN Reftable3
  ON basetable.id = Reftable3.BaseTableID
WHERE basetable.id = ?
```

Comment: There's a syntax error. You have to list the table names in the `DELETE` clause when there are multiple tables.